# Smooth tracking in Python and Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, tracking

Hi Everyone i am newbie in Python and opencv,

Can you guide me the best way to track human iris. I have created the ROI for iris but due to live stream when i pass the x and y co-ordinates of iris to it start to move randomly. This happens when next frame occupy the space of previous frame.

I have write the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import ctypes

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        frame=img
        if ret== True:
                egray = cv2.cvtColor(img ,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(egray ,1.3 ,5)
                for (x, y, w, h) in faces :
                    eyes=eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(egray)
                    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes :
                        if (ex>0)&(ey>0)&(ew>0)&(eh>0):
                                gray=egray[ey+25:ey+eh-10,ex+15:ex+ew-15]
                                (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
                                ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(minLoc[0],minLoc[1])
                                cv2.rectangle(img,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(255 , 0, 0), 2)

                cv2.imshow('Faces',img)
                cv2.imshow('Gray',egray)
                k = cv2.waitKey(30)& 0xff
                if k==27:
                        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```